# Enable Allow arbitrary Loads of App Transport Security Setting not working in XCODE 9.2 and iOS 11.2

Tags: ios, swift, info.plist, xcode9.2

I used same setting for enabling arbitrary load but now i faced some issues.I used alamofire for json parsing.
[image]

info.plist settings:

[image]

and error is :

[image]

Comment: Can share some email-password? so that I can check at my end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your info plist hierarchy for transport should be like this

[image]

Comment: wait i will check.

Comment: Instead of this, can you open any url in webview as a test case? If you dont have webview then take a temp webview and try any random url.

Comment: hi I tried with webview but again shows same ATS error. please give me source code of info.plist for hierarchy

Comment: Hey @dahiya_boy I fixed this is by doing Project file->info->Custom iOS Target Properties->Add ATS setting with Allow Arbitrary enable instead of adding directly in info.plist

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

> `NSAppTransportSecurity` provides the network layer security and only allow http secured urls.

There are 2 ways to solve this:

**Case 1:**

In your code you are using an unsecure url with `http://` replace it with `https://`, then it will work.

**Case 2:**

If you don't have ssl enabled url then, allow your url in `Exception Domains` as:

[image]

Comment: There is no issue with `http://` I tried this URL -> `http://linux-training.be/linuxfun.pdf` and it works prfect.