# How to display Image from a URL in SwiftUI

Tags: node.js, swift, swiftui

So I'm trying to create a content feed using data fetched from my Node.js server.

**Here I fetch data from my API:**

```
class Webservice {
    func getAllPosts(completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8000/albums")
     else {
     fatalError("URL is not correct!")
    }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
            let posts = try!
                JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data!); DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(posts)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

**Set the variables to the data fetched from the API:**

```
final class PostListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    init() {
        fetchPosts()
    }
    
    @Published var posts = [Post]()
    
    private func fetchPosts() {
        Webservice().getAllPosts {
            self.posts = $0
        }
    } 
}
```

**Post model:**

```
struct Post: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let path: String
    let description: String
}
```

**SwiftUI:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = PostListViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(model.posts) { post in
            HStack {
                Text(post.title)
                Image("http://localhost:8000/" + post.path)
                Text(post.description)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Text from `post.title` and `post.description` are displayed correctly but nothing displays from `Image`. How can I use a `URL` from my server to display with my image?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

### iOS 15 update:

you can use asyncImage in this way:

```swift
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://your_image_url_address"))
```

more info on Apple developers document:
[AsyncImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/asyncimage)

#### Using ObservableObject (Before iOS 15)

first you need to fetch image from url :

```swift
class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Data, Never>()
    var data = Data() {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(data)
        }
    }

    init(urlString:String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, self != nil else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self]
                self?.data = data
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

you can put this as a part of your Webservice class function too.

then in your ContentView struct you can set @State image in this way :

```swift
struct ImageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var imageLoader:ImageLoader
    @State var image:UIImage = UIImage()

    init(withURL url:String) {
        imageLoader = ImageLoader(urlString:url)
    }

    var body: some View {
        
            Image(uiImage: image)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width:100, height:100)
                .onReceive(imageLoader.didChange) { data in
                self.image = UIImage(data: data) ?? UIImage()
        }
    }
}
```

Also, this [tutorial](https://www.vadimbulavin.com/asynchronous-swiftui-image-loading-from-url-with-combine-and-swift/) is a good reference if you need more

Comment: Do I need to fetch the image from the url if I already fetched the path when I fetched all my data with `class WebService`?

Comment: Yes, in your data you just fetch your image URL, not the image itself, for load the image you should fetch data and cast it as a UIImage from data

Comment: this solution works but when I start scrolling in my app the images start to disappear? I'm using this as my image url: `ImageView(withURL: "http://localhost:8000/\(post.path)")`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60710997/images-disappear-in-list-as-i-scroll-swiftui-swift

Comment: the images disappear because every time you scroll it get the images again. for the solution you need to cache the images to prevent from load again

Comment: Can you show me how to do that in my other stackoverflow post?

Comment: Check your question

Comment: i can't see any image url??

Comment: in your answer i don't understand where actually we've to insert image url!

Comment: @steveSarsawa where you define your ImageView:  ImageView(withURL: image url)

Comment: @Mac3n actually i've done it, thanks for your reply

Comment: Image. onReceive is not getting called. No image is showing.

Comment: For a more detailed guide to `AsyncImage` in iOS 15 check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67919836/4995828.

Answer (score 26):

Try with this implementation:

```
    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "http://mydomain/image.png")!, 
               placeholder: { Text("Loading ...") },
               image: { Image(uiImage: $0).resizable() })
       .frame(idealHeight: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 * 3) // 2:3 aspect ratio
```

Looks simple, right?
This function has the ability to save in cache the images, and also to make an async image request.

Now, copy this in a new file:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import Combine

struct AsyncImage<Placeholder: View>: View {
    @StateObject private var loader: ImageLoader
    private let placeholder: Placeholder
    private let image: (UIImage) -> Image
    
    init(
        url: URL,
        @ViewBuilder placeholder: () -> Placeholder,
        @ViewBuilder image: @escaping (UIImage) -> Image = Image.init(uiImage:)
    ) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder()
        self.image = image
        _loader = StateObject(wrappedValue: ImageLoader(url: url, cache: Environment(\.imageCache).wrappedValue))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        content
            .onAppear(perform: loader.load)
    }
    
    private var content: some View {
        Group {
            if loader.image != nil {
                image(loader.image!)
            } else {
                placeholder
            }
        }
    }
}

protocol ImageCache {
    subscript(_ url: URL) -> UIImage? { get set }
}

struct TemporaryImageCache: ImageCache {
    private let cache = NSCache<NSURL, UIImage>()
    
    subscript(_ key: URL) -> UIImage? {
        get { cache.object(forKey: key as NSURL) }
        set { newValue == nil ? cache.removeObject(forKey: key as NSURL) : cache.setObject(newValue!, forKey: key as NSURL) }
    }
}

class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: UIImage?
    
    private(set) var isLoading = false
    
    private let url: URL
    private var cache: ImageCache?
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    private static let imageProcessingQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "image-processing")
    
    init(url: URL, cache: ImageCache? = nil) {
        self.url = url
        self.cache = cache
    }
    
    deinit {
        cancel()
    }
    
    func load() {
        guard !isLoading else { return }

        if let image = cache?[url] {
            self.image = image
            return
        }
        
        cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map { UIImage(data: $0.data) }
            .replaceError(with: nil)
            .handleEvents(receiveSubscription: { [weak self] _ in self?.onStart() },
                          receiveOutput: { [weak self] in self?.cache($0) },
                          receiveCompletion: { [weak self] _ in self?.onFinish() },
                          receiveCancel: { [weak self] in self?.onFinish() })
            .subscribe(on: Self.imageProcessingQueue)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] in self?.image = $0 }
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        cancellable?.cancel()
    }
    
    private func onStart() {
        isLoading = true
    }
    
    private func onFinish() {
        isLoading = false
    }
    
    private func cache(_ image: UIImage?) {
        image.map { cache?[url] = $0 }
    }
}

struct ImageCacheKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: ImageCache = TemporaryImageCache()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var imageCache: ImageCache {
        get { self[ImageCacheKey.self] }
        set { self[ImageCacheKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Done!

Original source code: https://github.com/V8tr/AsyncImage

Comment: AsyncImage(url: URL(string: item.imageUrl)!,
                                   placeholder: { Text("Loading ...") },
                                   image: { Image(uiImage: $0).resizable() })
                            .frame(width: 80, height: 57)

Only Text Loading .... visible....no image getting downloading.

Comment: Only a few images load for me. The rest just return the "Loading..." text.

Comment: @EthanStrider Are the images from https? 
Maybe you need to allow https execution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49611336/enable-allow-arbitrary-loads-of-app-transport-security-setting-not-working-in-xc

Comment: @MrMins I am using an `https` URL, but setting the `AllowsArbitraryLoads` key to `YES` (as per the linked info) didn't help.

Comment: @EthanStrider can you send me a sample url?

Comment: Does cache exist only in memory i.e. only while app is running? Quitting the app purges cache?

Comment: @PaulB I believe so, yes. It's an in-memory cache.

Answer (score 17):

Combining @naishta (iOS 13+) and @mrmins (placeholder & configure) answers, plus exposing `Image` (instead `UIImage`) to allow configuring it (resize, clip, etc)

Usage Example:

```swift
var body: some View {

  RemoteImageView(
    url: someUrl,
    placeholder: { 
      Image("placeholder").frame(width: 40) // etc.
    },
    image: { 
      $0.scaledToFit().clipShape(Circle()) // etc.
    }
  )

}
```

```swift
struct RemoteImageView<Placeholder: View, ConfiguredImage: View>: View {
    var url: URL
    private let placeholder: () -> Placeholder
    private let image: (Image) -> ConfiguredImage

    @ObservedObject var imageLoader: ImageLoaderService
    @State var imageData: UIImage?

    init(
        url: URL,
        @ViewBuilder placeholder: @escaping () -> Placeholder,
        @ViewBuilder image: @escaping (Image) -> ConfiguredImage
    ) {
        self.url = url
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.image = image
        self.imageLoader = ImageLoaderService(url: url)
    }

    @ViewBuilder private var imageContent: some View {
        if let data = imageData {
            image(Image(uiImage: data))
        } else {
            placeholder()
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        imageContent
            .onReceive(imageLoader.$image) { imageData in
                self.imageData = imageData
            }
    }
}

class ImageLoaderService: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image = UIImage()

    convenience init(url: URL) {
        self.init()
        loadImage(for: url)
    }

    func loadImage(for url: URL) {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data) ?? UIImage()
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome with iOS 15 and lower

Comment: In order to get the placeholder to work correctly, I had to drop the first instance of imageLoader that gets called with initial blank UIImage(). I replaced it with `.onReceive(imageLoader.$image.dropFirst())`

Answer (score 13):

Example for iOS 15+ with loader :

```
AsyncImage(
    url: URL(string: "https://XXX"),
    content: { image in
        image.resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 100)
    },
    placeholder: {
        ProgressView()
    }
)
```

Answer (score 11):

## `AsyncImage` with animation transactions, placeholders, and network phase states in iOS 15+!

As other answers have covered, `AsyncImage` is the recommended way to achieve this in `SwiftUI` but the new `View` is much more capable than the standard config shown here:

```
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://your_image_url_address"))
```

`AsyncImage` downloads images from URLs without `URLSession`s boilerplate. However, rather than simply downloading the image and displaying nothing while loading, Apple recommends using placeholders while waiting for the best UX. Oh, we can also display custom views for error states, and add animations to further improve phase transitions. :D

### Animations

We can add animations using `transaction:` and change the underlying `Image` properties between states. Placeholders can have a different aspect mode, image, or have different modifiers. e.g. `.resizable`.

Here's an example of that:

```
AsyncImage(
  url: "https://dogecoin.com/assets/img/doge.png",
  transaction: .init(animation: .easeInOut),
  content: { image in
  image
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
}, placeholder: {
  Color.gray
})
  .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
  .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
```

### Handling Network Result State

To display different views when a request fails, succeeds, is unknown, or is in progress, we can use a phase handler. This updates the view dynamically, similar to a `URLSessionDelegate` handler. Animations are applied automatically between states using SwiftUI syntax in a param.

```
AsyncImage(url: url, transaction: .init(animation: .spring())) { phase in
  switch phase {
  case .empty:
    randomPlaceholderColor()
      .opacity(0.2)
      .transition(.opacity.combined(with: .scale))
  case .success(let image):
    image
      .resizable()
      .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
      .transition(.opacity.combined(with: .scale))
  case .failure(let error):
    ErrorView(error)
  @unknown default:
    ErrorView()
  }
}
.frame(width: 400, height: 266)
.mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
```

### NOTE

We shouldn't use `AsyncImage` for all instances where we need to load an image from a URL. Instead, when images need to be downloaded on request, it's better to use the `.refreshable` or `.task` modifiers. Only use `AsyncImage` sparingly because the image will be re-downloaded for every `View` state change (streamline requests). Here, Apple suggests `await` to prevent blocking the main thread 0 (Swift 5.5+).

Answer (score 8):

**For iOS 13, 14** (before `AsyncImage`) and with the latest property wrappers ( without having to use `PassthroughSubject<Data, Never>()`

**Main View**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct TransactionCardRow: View {
    var transaction: Transaction

    var body: some View {
        CustomImageView(urlString: "https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png") // This is where you extract urlString from Model ( transaction.imageUrl)
    }
}
```

**Creating CustomImageView**

```
struct CustomImageView: View {
    var urlString: String
    @ObservedObject var imageLoader = ImageLoaderService()
    @State var image: UIImage = UIImage()
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: image)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width:100, height:100)
            .onReceive(imageLoader.$image) { image in
                self.image = image
            }
            .onAppear {
                imageLoader.loadImage(for: urlString)
            }
    }
}
```

**Creating a service layer to download the Images from url string, using a Publisher**

```
class ImageLoaderService: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: UIImage = UIImage()
    
    func loadImage(for urlString: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data) ?? UIImage()
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 5):

New in **iOS 15** , `SwiftUI` has a dedicated `AsyncImage` for downloading and displaying remote images from the internet. In its simplest form you can just pass a URL, like this:

```
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://www.thiscoolsite.com/img/nice.png"))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use KingFisher and SDWebImage

1. KingFisher
   https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

   ```
    var body: some View {
        KFImage(URL(string: "https://example.com/image.png")!)
    }
   ```
2. SDWebImage https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageSwiftUI

   ```
    WebImage(url: url)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
            Button(action: {
                    self.onClickImage()
                }, label: {
                    CustomNetworkImageView(urlString: self.checkLocalization())
                })
                
                Spacer()
            }
            
            if self.isVisionCountryPicker {
                if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                    Picker(selection: $selection, label: EmptyView()) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< self.countries.count) {
                            Text(self.countries[$0].name?[self.language] ?? "N/A").tag($0)
                        }
                    }
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .onChange(of: selection) { tag in self.countryChange(tag) }
                } else {
                    Picker(selection: $selection.onChange(countryChange), label: EmptyView()) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< self.countries.count) {
                            Text(self.countries[$0].name?[self.language] ?? "N/A").tag($0)
                        }
                    }
                    .labelsHidden()
                }
            }
```

fileprivate struct CustomNetworkImageView: View {
var urlString: String
@ObservedObject var imageLoader = ImageLoaderService()
@State var image: UIImage = UIImage()

```
var body: some View {
    Group {
        if image.pngData() == nil {
            if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                ProgressView()
                    .frame(height: 120.0)
                    .onReceive(imageLoader.$image) { image in
                        self.image = image
                        self.image = image
                        if imageLoader.image == image {
                            imageLoader.loadImage(for: urlString)
                        }
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        imageLoader.loadImage(for: urlString)
                    }
            } else {
                EmptyView()
                    .frame(height: 120.0)
                    .onReceive(imageLoader.$image) { image in
                        self.image = image
                        self.image = image
                        if imageLoader.image == image {
                            imageLoader.loadImage(for: urlString)
                        }
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        imageLoader.loadImage(for: urlString)
                    }
            }
        } else {
            Image(uiImage: image)
                .resizable()
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 150.0)
                .onReceive(imageLoader.$image) { image in
                    self.image = image
                    self.image = image
                    if imageLoader.image == image {
                        imageLoader.loadImage(for: urlString)
                    }
                }
                .onAppear {
                    imageLoader.loadImage(for: urlString)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

}

fileprivate class ImageLoaderService: ObservableObject {
@Published var image: UIImage = UIImage()

```
func loadImage(for urlString: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.image = UIImage(data: data) ?? UIImage()
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You also can try my way. This is the documentation link

> https://sdwebimage.github.io/documentation/sdwebimageswiftui/

Here is my code Snippet

```
struct SettingsProfileImageSectionView: View {
            var body: some View {
                ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Color(hex: "fcfcfc")
                    HStack(spacing: 20) {
                        Spacer()
                            .frame(width: 4)
                        CustomImageView(imageManager: ImageManager(url: URL(string: imageURL)))         }
                }
                .frame(height: 104)
            }
        }
```

**Load image from URL**

```
struct CustomImageView: View {
        @State private var myImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Icon/User")!
        @ObservedObject var imageManager: ImageManager
        var body: some View {
            Image(uiImage: myImage)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 56.0, height: 56.0)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .scaledToFit()
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .onReceive(imageManager.$image) { image in
                    if imageManager.image != nil {
                        myImage = imageManager.image!
                    }
                }
                .onAppear {self.imageManager.load()}
                .onDisappear { self.imageManager.cancel() }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with using `NSCache` in SwiftUI:

```swift
import UIKit

class CacheService {
    
    static let shared = CacheService() // Singleton
    private  init() {}
    
    var imageCache: NSCache<NSString, UIImage> = {
        let cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
        cache.countLimit = 100 // limits are imprecise
        cache.totalCostLimit = 1024 * 1024 * 100 // limit in 100mb
        return cache
    }()
    func addImage(image: UIImage, name: String) -> String {
        imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: name as NSString)
        return "Added to cach"
    }
    func removeImage(name: String) -> String {
        imageCache.removeObject(forKey: name as NSString)
        return "Removed from cach"
    }
    func getImage(name: String) -> UIImage? {
        return imageCache.object(forKey: name as NSString)
    }
}
```