# Images disappear in List as I scroll SwiftUI/Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I'm adding an Image to my SwiftUI list by getting(fetching) the path to the image and then using the image path to fetch the image from that url/path.

**Grabbing the data/path**

```
class Webservice {
    func getAllPosts(completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8000/albums")
     else {
     fatalError("URL is not correct!")
    }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in

            let posts = try!

                JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data!); DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(posts)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

**Variables**

```
struct Post: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {

    let id: String
    let title: String
    let path: String
    let description: String
}
```

**Setting the variables in `Post` to the posts in `completion(posts)` in `class Webservice`.**

```
final class PostListViewModel: ObservableObject {

    init() {
        fetchPosts()
    }

    @Published var posts = [Post]()

    private func fetchPosts() {
        Webservice().getAllPosts {
            self.posts = $0
        }
    }


}
```

**Fetch image from url/path**

```
class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Data, Never>()
    var data = Data() {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(data)
        }
    }

    init(urlString:String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.data = data
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

**Set @State image**

```
struct ImageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var imageLoader:ImageLoader
    @State var image:UIImage = UIImage()

    init(withURL url:String) {
        imageLoader = ImageLoader(urlString:url)
    }

    var body: some View {

            Image(uiImage: image)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width:100, height:100)
                .onReceive(imageLoader.didChange) { data in
                self.image = UIImage(data: data) ?? UIImage()
        }
    }
}
```

**Then display my image in a list using `ImageView` with the url/path from the data I fetched in the beginning which gets passed into `ImageLoader` to grab the image and set @State image in `ImageView`**

```
struct ContentView: View {
   init() {
            Webservice().getAllPosts {
                print($0)
            }
        }

    @ObservedObject var model = PostListViewModel()

        var body: some View {

                List(model.posts) { post in
                 VStack {
                    Text(post.title)
                    ImageView(withURL: "http://localhost:8000/\(post.path)")
                    Text(post.description)


                }
            }

        }

}
```

This code works to get the image at first but once I start scrolling here and there the images start to disappear. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

**Edit:** I was told to cache the images to prevent loading again. Does anyone know how I would do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

disappearing the image is because of reusing cells in the list and every time the cell reused it to fetch the image again, you need to cache the images to prevent it.

you can change your ImageLoader in this way and have a cache
you need to change the image in your ImageView too, instead of Data use UIImage

```swift
class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: UIImage?
    var urlString: String?
    var imageCache = ImageCache.getImageCache()
    
    init(urlString: String?) {
        self.urlString = urlString
        loadImage()
    }
    
    func loadImage() {
        if loadImageFromCache() {
            print("Cache hit")
            return
        }
        
        print("Cache miss, loading from url")
        loadImageFromUrl()
    }
    
    func loadImageFromCache() -> Bool {
        guard let urlString = urlString else {
            return false
        }
        
        guard let cacheImage = imageCache.get(forKey: urlString) else {
            return false
        }
        
        image = cacheImage
        return true
    }
    
    func loadImageFromUrl() {
        guard let urlString = urlString else {
            return
        }
        
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: getImageFromResponse(data:response:error:))
        task.resume()
    }
    
    
    func getImageFromResponse(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            print("No data found")
            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let loadedImage = UIImage(data: data) else {
                return
            }
            
            self.imageCache.set(forKey: self.urlString!, image: loadedImage)
            self.image = loadedImage
        }
    }
}
```

Cache class helper

```swift
class ImageCache {
    var cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
    
    func get(forKey: String) -> UIImage? {
        return cache.object(forKey: NSString(string: forKey))
    }
    
    func set(forKey: String, image: UIImage) {
        cache.setObject(image, forKey: NSString(string: forKey))
    }
}

extension ImageCache {
    private static var imageCache = ImageCache()
    static func getImageCache() -> ImageCache {
        return imageCache
    }
}
```

ImageView struct:

```swift
struct ImageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var imageLoader:ImageLoader

    init(withURL url:String) {
        imageLoader = ImageLoader(urlString:url)
    }

    var body: some View {

            Image(uiImage: imageLoader.image ?? UIImage() )
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width:100, height:100)
    }
}
```

Comment: What do I replace in this line?: `.onReceive(imageLoader.didChange) { data in self.image = UIImage(data: data) ?? UIImage()`

Comment: `.onReceive(imageLoader.didChange) { data in self.image = data}`

Comment: Hmmm. I used your code and my images still disappear

Comment: try to put `self.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: urlString as NSString)` in Dispatch and check it

Comment: I put it in Dispatch and it didn't do the trick. What would you like me to check?

Comment: I update my answer, Check it in this way, don't forget to change `ImageView` as I did

Comment: where do I put the `ImageCache` class?

Comment: In a new file or end of your ImageLoader, it doesn't matter

Comment: On this line `Image(imageLoader.image ?? UIImage() )` it's saying `Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage' to expected argument type 'String'`

Comment: It's a miss type `Image(uiImage: imageLoader.image ?? UIImage())`

Comment: Hey I don't know if all my images are loading but they're not disappearing so this works. Thanks

Comment: For a best practice, it is better to have a default placeholder image and set it to the placeholder instead of UIImage() , this way it's looking better. At least with a placeholder image

Comment: Does this work with large tables with rows of images?